# How to use ORDER by for colon separated column for sorting in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by

I have a column which has value in colon-separated example `2067:2063:2068:2066`. Now I want to order my select list using SQL query in the same order. Is this possible using SQL? I am aware of ORDER by id, name etc but this is a different scenario as it has value colon separated. Can someone suggest what needs to be done?

Comment: Meaning you want to reorder the values within the string?

Comment: Yes I want to order same as given example, these are ids from my select list

Comment: You haven't listed a decent example. Do you want to reorder the ids within the string? Or do you want to reorder your rows based on that string?

Comment: No not this string , I want to use this string for ordering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understood, you want to sort that list of numbers (separated by colons). This is ... what? Apex shuttle item or multiple selection list?

Anyway, see whether this helps:

```
SQL> WITH test AS (SELECT '2067:2063:2068:2066' item FROM DUAL),
  2       gimme_rows
  3       AS (    SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (item,
  4                                     '[^:]+',
  5                                     1,
  6                                     LEVEL)
  7                         res
  8                 FROM test
  9           CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT (item, ':') + 1)
 10  SELECT LISTAGG (res, ':') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY res) final_result
 11    FROM gimme_rows;

FINAL_RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------
2063:2066:2067:2068

SQL>
```

Comment: Yes, it is Apex shuttle

Comment: OK; so, does code I posted answers your question or not?

Answer (score 1):

The database doesn't really care what's in the string, it will sort by strings regardless of what is contained within them. That being said, poor database design is going to give you some really strange results.

If you have a row like you example, and a row with `2068:2064:2069:2067`, it's pretty clear that my example will come after the one listed in your example. Less obviously `2068:2064:2065:2066` would come after your example, but before mine. More confusingly, how those two get ordered with something like `2069:2099` is much harder to predict.

It's not even particularly easy to say what's correct behavior based on your use case. Databases really shouldn't contain listagg() values like that; I'd suggest storing the data better, personally.